# SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do some work with my SQL table.

I have 2 buildings with room numbers 1 - 100 in building 1 and 101 - 199 in building 2.
I have a location field (which I've just created) and want to run a query to populate it with either 'Building 1' or 'Building 2' depending on which room number it has in the 'Room' field.

Many thanks for your help.

Regards

Scott

Comment: @Galwegian: Can't understand why would you delete your post, if the answer is correct?

Comment: Galwegian posted an anwer that was correct, but has since deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx) to update your table:

```
Update your_table
Set location = Case When room_number <= 100 Then
                       'Building 1'
                    Else
                       'Building 2'
                    End;
```

If all of your room-numbers have three digits followed by some other characters, using `substring` should work:

```
Case When Cast( Substring( room_number, 1, 3 ) As Int ) <= 100 Then
```

Since not all of your rooms start with three digits (`1A`) you can use `PatIndex` to find the length of the number:

```
Case When
   Cast(
      Substring( room_number, 1, PatIndex( '%[A-Z]%', room_number || 'A' ) - 1 )
   As Int ) <= 100
Then
```

I'm concatenating the `A` to make sure it also works with numerical room-numbers.

Comment: Thanks.  How would I get it to cope with room numbers such as 120Z and 121Y ?

Comment: If all of your room numbers are 3 digits and a single character, you could use a SUBSTRING on the room number and compare that value in the case statement.

Comment: My room numbers go from 1 to 500 and have others inbetween such as 120X, 121G, etc (only about 20 rooms though).

Comment: Would it make it a real pain if my room field was nvarchar ? (which it is)

Comment: Thanks. When I run it I get an error....
'Syntax error converting the nvarchar value '1A' to a column of data type int'

Comment: @Scott Jackson: Please see my next update. Can't try it right now, not sure if the offset (`-1`) is correct.